# Just added the art-history tag - worthwhile?

Tags: discussion, tags

The title should be fairly clear. I asked a question connected with the history and/or appreciation of art and it struck me that this was a topic that overlaps literature with a reasonable frequency - look at the connections between William Carlos Willams and artists like Man Ray, Charles Demuth and Marcel Duchamp for example.

Is it a keeper, or shall I expunge it?

Comment: @verbose hmm. Perhaps i didn't add it but put this question up to gauge the reaction first. Anyway, I've added it now

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there are deep links between art history and literature. The current mix of questions on the site probably doesn't quite reflect this, but a a tag is on-topic, and might (slightly) encourage people thinking of asking a fine art + literature question.